# Not able to create array from 1 cell range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that reads ranges and converts them to arrays for processing.
It unfortunately fails when the range only has one cell.

To boil down the problem, consider the following ranges (r1, r2) with respectively 1 and 2 cells, that I want to convert to arrays a1 and a2, respectively:

```
Sub ranges_to_arrays()

    Dim r1 As Range, r2 as Range
    Dim a1() As Variant, a2() as Variant

    Set r2 = Worksheets("test").Range("A1:A2")
    a2 = r2 ' Creates Variant(1 to 2, 1 to 1)

    Set r1 = Worksheets("test").Range("A1")
    a1 = r1 'Fails with a type mismatch

End Sub
```

How can I ensure that an array will be created even if the range has only one element?

Comment: This is a design "feautre" of excel that has led to many bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check how many cells there are in your Range you are trying to convert to array, use `If r2.Cells.Count > 1 Then`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ranges_to_arrays()

    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim a1() As Variant, a2() As Variant

    Set r2 = Worksheets("test").Range("A1:A2")
    If r2.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        a2 = r2 ' Creates Variant(1 to 2, 1 to 1)
    Else
        ReDim a2(0 To r2.Cells.Count - 1) ' redim array size to 1 (only 1 cell in range)
        a2(0) = r2
    End If

    Set r1 = Worksheets("test").Range("A1")
    If r1.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        a1 = r1 'Fails with a type mismatch
    Else
        ReDim a1(0 To r1.Cells.Count - 1) ' redim array size to 1 (only 1 cell in range)
        a1(0) = r1
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have afterwards to deal necessarily with a two-dimensional array (e.g., to loop through the values), then

```
If r2.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    a2 = r2
ElseIf r2.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim a(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    a2(1, 1) = r2
End If
```

And the second advantage of this is that LBound will be 1 in both cases, because converting multiple cells to an array always returns an array with LBound 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Excel changes what `.Value` and `.Value2` returns depending if a single cell is referenced, or not.

To get consistent results you would need a wrapper function

```
Option Explicit

Public Function RangeGetArray(ByVal r As Range) As Variant()
    Dim data() As Variant
    If r.Rows.Count = 1 And r.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        data(1, 1) = r.Value
    Else
        data = r.Value
    End If
    RangeGetArray = data
End Function

Public Function RangeSetArray(ByVal r As Range, ByRef data() As Variant)
    Dim n As Long, m As Long
    n = UBound(data, 1) - LBound(data, 1) + 1
    m = UBound(data, 2) - LBound(data, 2) + 1
    If n = 1 And m = 1 Then
        r.Value = data(1, 1)
    Else
        r.Resize(n, m).Value = data
End Function
```